# Rails 3: habtm migration, primary key issue

Tags: migration, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to setup a migration file for a habtm relationship, however when I run the migration I'm getting the following error:

> Primary key is not allowed in a
>   has_and_belongs_to_many join table
>   (parts_vehicles).

Here is my migration file (20110111035950_create_parts_vehicles.rb):

```
class CreatePartsVehiclesJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :parts_vehicles, :id => false do |t|
      t.integer :part_id
      t.integer :vehicle_id
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :parts_vehicles
  end
end
```

[The documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) example states to use `:id => false` to disable a primary key from being generated, but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: It looks correct. Run `rake db:migrate:status` to make sure this migration is `down`.

Comment: Yes it is correct. It started working when I dropped my DB and re-ran migrations.

Answer (score 1):

1.) You're class name should be the same as your migration name:

```
class CreatePartsVehicles < ActiveRecord::Migration
```

2.) Did you migrate? Try dropping your db (rake db:drop) and remigrating (rake db:migrate)

Comment: The class name of a migration doesn't matter here.

Comment: wasn't sure. better safe than sorry. i feel like he just didn't migrate correctly though

Comment: I was using a special rake task to do db:drop:all db:migrate and db:seed, which apparently was having some issues. It started working once I executed each step manually.

Comment: Like I said - 'i feel like he just didn't migrate correctly' :)